# Import MinGW compiler in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2017, mingw

Halo to the community,

I have created a WIN32 C++ Solution-project in Visual Studio 2017. I want the files of the WIN32 application to be compiled by the MinGW compiler and then be able to debug the application using Visual Studio 2017.

I am trying to follow [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/07/19/using-mingw-and-cygwin-with-visual-cpp-and-open-folder/) tutorial in order to import the MinGw compiler. I understand that this tutorial is referring to the [MinGW-w64 project](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) but I want to import the MinGW compiler found [here](http://www.mingw.org/).

Can you please help me make the right associations in the "CppProperties.json" and the "tasks.vs.json" files?

My "CppProperties.json" at the moment looks like this:

```
{  "configurations": [
{
  "inheritEnvironments": [
    "msvc_x86"
  ],
  "name": "x86-Debug",
  "includePath": [
    "${env.INCLUDE}"
  ],
  "defines": [
    "WIN32",
    "_DEBUG",
    "UNICODE",
    "_UNICODE"
  ],
  "intelliSenseMode": "windows-clang-x86"
},
{
  "inheritEnvironments": [
    "msvc_x86"
  ],
  "name": "x86-Release",
  "includePath": [
    "${env.INCLUDE}"
  ],
  "defines": [
    "WIN32",
    "NDEBUG",
    "UNICODE",
    "_UNICODE"
  ],
  "intelliSenseMode": "windows-clang-x86"
}
], 
"environments": [
{
  "MINGW_PREFIX": "C:\\MinGW",
  "MINGW_CHOST ": "x86_64-w64-mingw32",
  "MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX": "mingw-w64-x86_64",
  "MSYSTEM": "MINGW64",
  "MSYSTEM_CARCH": "x64_64",
  "MSYSTEM_PREFIX": "${env.MINGW_PREFIX}",
  "SHELL": "${env.MINGW_PREFIX}/../usr/bin/bash",
  "TEMP": "${env.MINGW_PREFIX}/../tmp",
  "TMP": "${env.TEMP}",
  "PATH": "${env.MINGW_PREFIX}/bin;${env.MINGW_PREFIX}/../usr/local/bin;${env.MINGW_PREFIX}/../usr/bin;${env.PATH}",
  "INCLUDE": "project/lib/include;${env.MINGW_PREFIX}/mingw/include"
}  
]
}
```